# Qual a origem do termo "bê-á-bá"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões

Faria sentido para mim se fosse "be-à-bu", compreendendo todas as sílabas com b, mas "bê-á-bá" não consigo perceber a origem da expressão.

Answer (score 6):

Se te pedisse para soletrar *bá*, o que me dirias? Provavelmente "bê, á. Bá", ou seja, primeiro listarias as letras (esquerda–direita), soletrando, e depois dirias a palavra: "bê, á. Bá". Eis *bê-á-bá*! Assim diz o Houaiss.

Answer (score 4):

**Complementando a resposta anterior**, "bê-á-bá" tornou-se uma palavra presente nos dicionários e a forma correta é bê-á-bá (com acento nos dois "aa"). Plural: bê-á-bás).   Em sentido figurado, significa noções iniciais de algum assunto ou atividade.

ex. Ainda estou no bê-á-bá, mas daqui a alguns meses serei um expert no assunto.

E o [**Priberam**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/b%C3%AA-%C3%A1-b%C3%A1) define como "primeiras noções de uma arte, de uma ciência, de uma  atividade ou de um assunto."

Answer (score 2):

A origem da expressão seria dos métodos antigos de alfabetização (antigos -> década de 60 ou 70), quando os professores, para ensinar a ler e a escrever, ensinavam o alfabeto e o som das letras em conjunto. Bê-á-bá era a primeira união - B + A - que o professor ensinava, pois era composta pelas duas primeiras letras do alfabeto (imagina agora um professor dizendo "todos juntos, turma, Be com A..." e a turma responde "BA").

Por isso, hoje, apesar de não se ensinar a ler e escrever dessa forma (eu mesmo, com quase 40 anos, não aprendi dessa forma, mas meus pais e avós sim), virou uma espécie de gíria para indicar algo bem simples sobre um determinado assunto.

Comment: Bem-vindo Leonardo, obrigado pela contribuição. +1 Sua explicação me parece bem provável, mas seria ótimo se você pudesse incluir alguma fonte pois, como está, é pouco mais que uma hipótese.